# jquery plugin clue

Tags: jquery-plugins

what is the jquery plugin is in the right bottom of this page?

http://www.suite101.com/content/rights-managed-vs-royalty-free-a57320

Comment: suite101.com is gone which makes this question vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a jquery plugin, it's a service from these guys..

http://www.kissinsights.com/

Answer (score 0):

Could be AddToAny.